# How to recover jam that is too liquid?

Tags: food-preservation, jam, pectin, consistency

I made redcurrant jam some months ago, with sugar/pectin-mix. I used the appropriate amount. However, the mix was very old (+5 years). I tried it anyway. The jam turned out like a syrup, it is very liquid, but the taste is fine.

If I heat my jam/syrup and I add some new-bought pectin, would it turn out fine?

Comment: I would just use it as-is, in glazes and such. Or put some in a tall glass and add seltzer water to make a lovely drink.

Comment: I put some on my panna cotta last week, but there are still a lot of jars waiting for a purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done this before and it has worked for me. It should work, but if it doesn't, I know what will. My aunt sold Jam for a while and when the pectin didn't work she reheated and added a small amount of gelatin, I helped her stir it in, and that was the final fix for her bad mix.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a bit of sun (as it is a summertime method);
* Pour the jam into a tray and leave it under the sun for some days. Check and stir the jam time to time until it reaches to desired thichness.
*The top of the tray should be covered with a thin cotton cloth/muslin in case any dust etc. not to get into the jam while it is still having sun and breating.

Otherwise I would use it to prepare lovely drinks as `Marti` suggested instead of boiling it again.

Comment: This is climate dependent. I wouldn't use it in Belgium, the climate isn't hot or dry enough even in the summer. Southern Europe and similar climates, it should be OK, if the jam is sugary enough to not spoil.